# IDLE - Python: Go back to a certain line, how can I do this?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-idle

I've created a selection menu that asks you to input the command you want to run, I've done this by using `if` and `elif` statements however when the command (the if statements) has finished I would like them to go to the line asking which command to run. Here is the code I have at the moment (Right now I have nothing that does this):

```py
# Asks which command you want to run.
word = input("Which command? ")

# Runs the command/s.

if word == "info":
    print("Info command.")
    
elif word == "replace":
    print("Replace command.")

elif word == "ping":
    print("Ping command")

else:
    print("Command not found")
```

It would be awesome if someone could help, thanks.

Comment: put everything inside a `while True` loop. You casn find examples of how `while` works in the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this is too much, but you might want to consider putting it into a function to do something like this:

```
def main():
    # Asks which command you want to run.
    word = input("Which command? ").strip().lower()

    # Runs the command/s.

    if word == "info":
        print("Info command.")

    elif word == "replace":
        print("Replace command.")

    elif word == "ping":
        print("Ping command")

    elif word == "quit":
        return False

    else:
        print("Command not found")
    return True

while main():
    pass
```

This would be the same thing as `while True` then `if something: break`

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your code in a `while True:` block. This will repeat the code indefinitely.

For further reading try [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

Comment: While:True ? is this Python ?